# commit or rollback set of Changes in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am new to SVN , we are using SVN version controller in eclipse (Lunar), We have a module,that module code's may go to Release or may not go to release depends on the business approval, is there any way in SVN to commit/rollback set of changes(different File changes) on single action ?

Thanks & Regards
S.Sathiya

Answer (score 0):

To roll back changes in Subversion while maintaining the history of all events, you need to perform what's known as a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo). You're essentially applying a patch which reverses the changes that were done between "now" and the state you want to roll back to.

You can apply a reverse merge to a whole tree/subtree, or individual elements (files/directories). To make things easy, work in the largest chunks you can manage.

Answer (score -1):

Simply check out the version of the file you would like to have and commit it to the repo. Reverting is a feature to undo accidental *whole* commits (so it would have an effect on other files too, which is probably undesired). If the whole thing you want to undo is a complete commit, then yes, reverting under the *Team* context menu or in the history is what you are searching for.

Comment: This is incorrect. `Revert` in Subversion undoes *local* changes that have not yet been committed. It does not change the state of the repository. Single items can be reverted.

Comment: Hm, yeah, you say something, there's a bit of terminology conflict here. The reverting does undo the local changes compared to the latest version of the file indeed. Nevertheless, the client allow to _Revert changes of revision_ (the SVN plugins of Eclipse can do that in the _History_ view). And since the OP asked how to do that in Eclipse, and they call it also *reverting*, I used the same word :-)